# JS/Jquery scope issue on change and keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am trying to have JS/Jquery collect up multiple form fields to then post to an API.

Whenever I change the select or one of the inputs I only ever get the value of the one that I changed and the data fields

```js
$(".mat-sel").on("change keyup", function() {
  let areaId = $(this).data('area');
  let optionId = $(this).data('option');
  let buildingId = $(this).data('building');
  let choice = $('#type-' + buildingId + '-' + optionId + '-' + areaId).find(":selected").val();
  let length = $('#l-' + buildingId + '-' + optionId + '-' + areaId).val();
  let height = $('#h-' + buildingId + '-' + optionId + '-' + areaId).val();
  console.log('Area: ' + areaId);
  console.log('Option: ' + optionId);
  console.log('Building: ' + buildingId);
  console.log('Choice: ' + choice);
  console.log('Length: ' + length);
  console.log('Height: ' + height);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="material-picker-3">
  <div class="collapse show">
    <div class="row g-3 my-0 line-collector material">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5>Type</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select id="type-6-5-3" data-building="6" data-option="5" data-area="3" class="form-select mat-sel">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="1">STANDARD</option>
          <option value="1">CUSTOM</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse show">
    <div class="row g-3 my-0 line-collector material">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5>Total Length</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text " id="basic-addon1">mm</span> 
          <input id="l-6-1-3" value="0" data-building="6" data-option="1" data-area="3" class="form-control mat-sel l-box" type="number" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse show">
    <div class="row g-3 my-0 line-collector material">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5>Total Height</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text " id="basic-addon1">mm</span> 
          <input id="h-6-2-3" value="0" data-building="6" data-option="2" data-area="3" class="form-control mat-sel h-box" type="number" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Select: 1 (change from 0)
Input1: unchanged (default val 0)
Input2: unchanged (default val 0)

Output:
Area: 3
Option: 5
Building: 6
Choice: 1
Length: undefined
Height: undefined

---

Select: 1
Input1: 586
Input2: unchanged (default val 0)

Output:
Area: 3
Option: 5
Building: 6
Choice: undefined
Length: 586
Height: undefined

Comment: Please note you should never have duplicated passwords `id="basic-addon1"`

Comment: Also when you select something your selector is looking for element with id `l-6-5-3`. You don't have any of those. Also both `STANDARD` and `CUSTOM` have same value

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.